# return '+' +n if positive number

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this following one-liner.

```
  data = ({id:x.toString(),text: x.toFixed(2)} for x in [params.min..params.max] by params.step)
```

the parent function takes in a max, min, and step.  It creates options in a combobox through this.  IE, [10, 1, 10] would leave me with an option box with 20 selections: -10..0..10.

This works fine, but I need to display a '+' when the number is positive.  I can't, for the life of me, figure out, syntactically, where to put this conditional.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a conditional expression. CoffeeScript `if...then...else` blocks can be used as expressions, so the following expression

```
(if x > 0 then '+' else '') + x
```

would produce a `+` sign if the number is positive.

You can simply insert that into your existing code like so:

```
data = ({ id: x.toString(), text: (if x > 0 then '+' else '') + x.toFixed(2) } for x in [params.min..params.max] by params.step)
```

Comment: YES. works awesomely. i just spent the past 3 hours screwing up the syntax for this, thanks for your quick response